# UIView's are not positioning correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a nib with a 2 UIViews and 2 UILabels with IBOutlet's in my controller.

I am increasing and decreasing the height of these UIViews to look like a bar to indicate when something is 100% or less - like a bar chart almost.

I am using the following method for both bars (reuse) however the first UIView (bar) positions correctly but the second is too low down - the Y axis is wrong. However the height of both is correct.

Anyone have any ideas?  I have positioned them in interface builder already all I am actually doing in this method is changing the height (basically)

```
//Position the point, size and label of a rating bar
- (void)configureRatingBar:(UIView *)vRatingBar 
            andRatingLabel:(UILabel *)lRatingLabel
               usingRating:(NSDecimalNumber *)rating
{
    //NSDecimalNumber *foodRating = [self calculateRating:self.currentHotel.foodAndBeverageRating];
    NSString *formattedRating = [self formatRating:rating];
    lRatingLabel.text = formattedRating;

    float newHeight = [rating floatValue]; //The height will be based on the rating 100 max
    CGRect currentFrame = vRatingBar.frame; //Current frame of the rating view

    //CGPoint currentPoint = 
    //  [vRatingBar convertPoint:vRatingBar.frame.origin toView:vReviews];




    CGPoint currentPoint = vRatingBar.frame.origin; //Current point of the rating view
    float newYaxis = currentPoint.x + (100 - newHeight); //Y axis must move down with the decreasing rating from 0 (100 %) down

    [vRatingBar setFrame:CGRectMake(currentPoint.x, newYaxis, currentFrame.size.width, newHeight)]; 
    [lRatingLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(currentFrame.size.width / 34, newHeight - 20, 34, 21)];   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have this line:

```
float newYaxis = currentPoint.x + (100 - newHeight); //Y axis must move down with the decreasing rating from 0 (100 %) down
```

Where you are using currentPoint.x for the calculation.  Should this be currentPoint.y?

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks mate. I could not understand why the first 'control' was plotting correctly but the second one wasn't - must have just be a fluke!  You rock!